# How to prevent app container URL from getting exposed in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, webkit, wkwebview

In iOS, when a link with improper value in href attribute (say for example: `<a href = "{SomeDynamicFieldTobeResolvedLaterAsLink}">Link</a>`) is dragged and dropped into `WKWebView`, the path of the application is exposed like this:

```
file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A26FB816-FBA1-427D-BC8C-8F425C296676/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/59625BC8-A075-465F-802D-9F0C77D75488/
```

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Add `UIDropInteraction` to `WKWebView`.
2. Load a sample HTML that has an anchor tag like mentioned in above example.
3. Try to hold the link, you will get plus icon and view showing that the link can be dropped.
4. If that link is dropped anywhere in `WKWebView`, the container URL is exposed as mentioned above.

Note that this occurs in actual iPhones too. I don't want this container path to be exposed while drag and drop is done. Is there any way to prevent this ?

Comment: What is an "improper value in href attribute"?

Comment: @Sweeper Pls find an example in the edited question

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. How do you "drop" a link on a `WKWebView`? I cannot drop a link onto a `WKWebView` by default.

Comment: @Sweeper have edited the question. Hope it is clear now